# How to maintain variable values between function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm building a function for filling a buffer, which is called several times. I declare the `rep_counter` to maintain his value after every pass, but when I call it again, it resets to 0. I tried declaring it as `self.rep_counter` inside a `def __init__`, tried to declare it as a `global` function, but without any luck. How can I do it? Here is my actual code:

```
import gym
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v0')
env.reset()
action_size = env.action_space.n
state_size = env.observation_space.shape
steps =  0 
step_counter = 0          
total_reward = 0
i = 0
i_update = i
episodes = 100010
img_batch_size = 4
img_batch = []
state1, reward1, _, _ = env.step(0)
batch_shape = (1,80,80,4)
img_batch = [state1,state1,state1,state1]
exp_batch = []
rep_batch = []
rep_batch_size = 4
rep_counter = 0
memory_length = 2
memory = deque((), maxlen = memory_length)
rep_batch = deque((), maxlen = rep_batch_size)


class AI:          
    def replay(self, exp_batch, rep_counter):
        if rep_counter < rep_batch_size:
            rep_counter += 1
            rep_batch.append(exp_batch)            
        else:
            if len(memory) < memory_length:
                memory.append(rep_batch)
            else:
                memory.popleft()
                memory.append(rep_batch)
            rep_batch.popleft()
            rep_batch.append(exp_batch)
            rep_counter = 0


    def buffer_processing(img_batch):
        processed_batch = [cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(x,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY),(80,80)) for x in img_batch]
        processed_batch = [[x/255.0]for x in processed_batch]
        processed_batch = np.asarray(processed_batch)
        processed_batch.shape = batch_shape
        return processed_batch

    a = buffer_processing(img_batch)

for i in range (episodes):
    total_reward = 0

    for steps in range (10000):
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        total_reward += reward
        state = next_state
        exp_batch = (state, action, next_state, reward, done)
        agent = AI()
        agent.replay(exp_batch, rep_counter)
        exp_batch = []
        step_counter += 1
```

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve], this is missing the entire start of the function (including where and how `rep_counter` is declared) and how it is called

Comment: wait. you set it to 0 in else, then wonder why its 0?

Comment: I edited the code to add the information needed. Tell me if it's enough.

Comment: `rep_counter` is a function parameter that shadows the global variable - also I don't see the `global` keyword anywhere in that code

Comment: So it needs to be declared as ```global rep_counter``` ? I tried it and it doesn't worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for a minimal complete working example as specified in the comments here are possible suggestions.

You can declare it global and then inside the function reference it as `global rep_counter` before its usage.

You can declare it as an instance variable inside any method (better if `__init__`) as `self.rep_counter`.

You can declare it as  class variable (its value is shared among all instances):

```
class AI:
    rep_counter
```

and call it as `AI.rep_counter`.

If we are talking about pure functions, you can use a method that recalls the C/C++ static keyword:

```
def myFunction():
    ...
    myFunction.NumberOfCalls += 1

myFunction.NumberOfCalls = 0
```

Comment: I edited and added all the code. I'm going to try your suggestions.

Comment: Declaring it as a class variable made it work! Thanks a lot.